# How do I redirect users to the appropriate login, if my app contains two different login pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know that I can use [Authorize] to prevent a page from being hit without a user being logged in. In this case, I have 2 different logins to my application(a user and an admin). To explain better, lets take for instance the following request come in through the url when the user is not logged in:

```
foo/bar/create/2
```

With the authorize attribute above the corresponding action result this user will be directed to the default login page.

```
account/login
```

How do I instead, redirect the user to `account/userlogin` for that specific `Create` action result?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Authorize Attribute and override the **HandleUnauthorizedRequest**

```
    public class ClientAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public new String Role { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return DoAUthorizationAndReturnBool(Role);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
            if(Role=="Admin")
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "admin", action = "login" }));
            else
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "user", action = "login" }));
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using forms autentication with a MembershipProvider, you can get the `FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl` method. This method "Returns the redirect URL for the original request that caused the redirect to the login page.". Inspect that url to find out what url they were attempting to navigate to, and after logging in, redirect to that url.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getredirecturl(v=vs.110).aspx

We are doing something similar (detecting if they are attempting to hit the salesportal, or the admin portal):

```
<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Function Login(model As LoginModel) As ActionResult
    If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
        Dim userValid = Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password)
        If (userValid) Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, False)
            Dim membershipProvider = New Program.Security.MoleculeraMembershipProvider()
            Dim redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.Email, False)
            If redirectUrl.Contains("sales") Then
                Return RedirectToAction("SalesPortal")
            Else
                Return RedirectToAction("AdminPortal")
            End If
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.")
        End If
    End If
    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

You can also just redirect to the url directly:

```
<HttpPost>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Function Login(model As LoginModel) As ActionResult
    If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
        Dim userValid = Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password)
        If (userValid) Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, False)
            Dim membershipProvider = New Program.Security.MoleculeraMembershipProvider()
            Dim redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.Email, False)
            Return Redirect(returnUrl)
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.")
        End If
    End If
    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

*I apologize in advance for this being in VB.NET. It's an old app.*